# what is _MultiThreadedRendezvous in grpc and how to parse it

Tags: grpc, grpc-python

I'm trying to send a grpc request and I'm expected to receive stream of message back. Instead I'm receiving a response as <_MultiThreadedRendezvous object>. Can anyone help me to understand why I'm receiving this and what should I do to extract the expected message from this object. The server is C++ and client is python in this case.

Answer (score 11):

Please take a look at gRPC's [example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/fcce56df4ea02f08cb0cf75757bf396f59a90e68/examples/python/route_guide/route_guide_client.py#L96) of streaming RPC. The `_MultiThreadedRendezvous` object is the library's representation of an RPC result. It is an iterable, you can use `for` to fetch all responses, or you can use `list()` to get all messages.

Comment: What you shared is really helpful. But sometime I receive no messages from that iterator sometimes I do. Have you experienced that. @lidi

Comment: There are many possibility that could lead to that behavior. Generally, client should receive all the messages sent by peer. If you believe it is a bug in gRPC library, please create a reproduction case and submit an issue to https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues.

Comment: No worries. I don't think it is due to grpc library. Something wrong on my side of code.

Comment: loop it through the `for` loop solved this, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using `e.code()` and `e.details()` helped me parsing it:

```py
try:
    response = stub.SayHello(...)
except _MultiThreadedRendezvous as e:
    if e.code() == grpc.StatusCode.CANCELLED:
        pass 
        # process cancelled status

    elif e.code() == grpc.StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE and 'Connection reset by peer' in e.details():
        pass 
        # process unavailable status

    else:
        raise
```

Looking at the [source code of that error](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/python/grpcio/grpc/_channel.py) helped me understand how to parse it.

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64578855/3508719) on another question.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent few hours on the same issue and i've figured out that `_MultiThreadedRendezvous` returned could be because of some issue has occurred. This is not the normal behavior of grpc.

For my case, i've NOT kept the `.proto` file up to date for both of my services.

I'm setting up a microservices with 2 services: grpc-service and bff-service. Both services have the same `.proto` file because they need to contact to each other.

But i've changed the `.proto` file of grpc-service, but not update in bff-serivce, which led to this issue. I've updated it to be the same as each other, and it's worked.

Hope this information helped someone.